# vuejs-datepicker not show

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I need some help.  The input box doesn't seem to be appearing.  I am not using app.js as it gives me problem with Buefy.  Anything I did wrongly? Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="{{ asset('js/vue2.4.2.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/buefy0.4.6.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/axios.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <hr>
  <div class="container">
      <datepicker name="test" placeholder="European Format ('d-m-Y')" :config="{ dateFormat: 'd-m-Y', static: true }"></datepicker>
  </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Vue.use(Buefy.default)
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          components: {
          'datepicker': DatePicker
          },
          data: {
            name:'test'
          },
          methods: {
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
components: {
  'datepicker': Buefy.Datepicker
}
```

Comment: it prompts me error Unknown custom element: <datepicker>.  The datepicker is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker not Buefy.  Not sure why I just can't use app.js even I have run the npm dev run.  The error is "ReferenceError: Buefy is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

In the app.js file

```
import Buefy from 'buefy';
Vue.use(Buefy);
```

Do not use

```
Vue.use(Buefy.Default);
```